# Xamarin Forms: How to create an Epub Viewer in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, epub

I am trying to implement an epub viewer in xamarin forms like the below video.

Video Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jW33lstCXqwC35siYklLoXAxItWpQG8c/view?usp=sharing

At first, I need to show the TOC of the book. If taps any chapter in TOC need to show that chapter on the UI. The total chapters and current chapter details are added at the bottom of the page. We can change the font size, font style, light and dark theme, and horizontal and vertical swiping features. Also able to hear the chapter in audio voice. Please have a look at the above video.

**This is the native Android implementation. I need to do this feature in xamarin forms, following are my queries.**

1. Is xamarin offer an epub viewer like this? Or I need to do all these features custom?
2. I tried [EpubReader.Cross](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross) NuGet package, but it has no TOC list.
3. How can I change the font size and font style like the video?
4. For audio voice feature I can use text to speech feature, but when reading the book by voice how can I highlight the text?
5. There is a package named [epubReader](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=epubreader), it has a TOC list. But when I try to install it to the project, I am getting [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T0C9_YiTRSJCE1X5bYI6BEUoftEizkWG/view?usp=sharing) error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is xamarin offer an epub viewer like this? Or I need to do all these features custom?

   Xamarin forms do not provide this  epun viewer like this. If you want to change the
   font size, font style and add TTS function(need highlight the text), features custom
   is a way that have to go.
2. I tried `EpubReader.Cross` NuGet package, but it has no TOC list.

   You can create TOC list, `EpubReader.Cross` provide the Enumerating chapters by `epubBook.Chapters`
3. How can I change the font size and font style like the video?
4. For audio voice feature I can use text to speech feature, but when reading the book by voice how can I highlight the text?

   Based on my research, you have to make a features custom,
5. There is a package named epubReader, it has a TOC list. But when I try to install it to the project, I am getting this error.

   If you use `epubReader`, this nuget package is too old and not updated in years, it cannot compat with current Android and iOS version.

If others know a better solution, please share it.